# How do I add a method to a class from a third-party Python module without editing the original module

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm using the `Basemap` object from `basemap` module in the matplotlib toolkit (`mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap`). In `basemap`'s `__init__.py` file (i.e. the `mpl_toolkits.basemap.__init__` module), a method `drawparallels` is defined which draws latitudes on the map. I aim to duplicate that method to make a new method called `drawmlat`, making some adjustments in order to plot magnetic latitudes instead of geographic latitudes.

Ideally, I want the new `drawmlat` to be equivalent to the original `drawparallel` (a bound method of the instances of Basemap that I can call with using `BasemapInstance.drawmlats()`), and I do not want to modify the original file. How would I accomplish this?

I have tried variations of the "recipe" `MyObj.method = MethodType(new_method, None, MyObj)`, but without placing anything in the original source file, the new method does not have access to globals etc. from the Basemap module (e.g. defined in its `__init__.py`).

If it seems I have misunderstood something, I probably have - I am more or less completely new to object-oriented programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is highly modifiable. Just add your function to the *class*:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


def drawmlat(self, arg1, arg2, kw=something):
    pass

Basemap.drawmlat = drawmlat
```

Now the `Basemap` class has a `drawmlat` method; call it on instances and `self` will be bound to the instance object. When looking up the method on instances, the function will automatically be bound as a method for you.

Anything defined in the `Basemap.__init__` method that you need to care about are attributes on `self`.

Having looked over the `mpl_toolkits.basemap.__init__` module, I do see that the `drawparallel` method relies on a *few* globals; you can import those from the module into your own namespace:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, _cylproj, _pseudocyl
```

This is no different from other imports you'd make; the original `drawparallel` method also relies on `import numpy as np` and `from matplotlib.lines import Line2D`, which make both `np` and `Line2D` globals in the original module.

Comment: Doesn't work. the `mpl_toolkits.basemap` module (folder) (note lower-case b) contains the file `__init__.py`, in which the `Basemap` class (uppercase B) is defined. The methods of the `Basemap` class use globals defined within this `__init__.py` file, but defined outside the `Basemap` class. When I follow your advice, but instead replace your dummy `drawmlat` function with an identical copy of the already-existing `drawparallels` method, I get `NameError: global name '_cylproj' is not defined` where `_cylproj` is one of the globals I mentioned which are used in the `drawparallels` method.

Comment: @cmeeren: You can import the additional globals from that module into your own. I'll take a look at the exact source code.

Comment: @cmeeren: And my apologies, I thought you were talking about the `Basemap.__init__` method, not the `mpl_toolkits.basemap.__init__` module.

Comment: @martijn-pieters, I can see I should have been clearer on this (updated). Thank you for the answer. I ran out of space on my comment. :p

Comment: @martijn-pieters, you can view the `__init__.py` file in question here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvfht9jcyw03a61/__init__.py

Comment: Yes, and I already saw it by looking at the Sourceforge project repository. Any global names you need can be imported from the same location as `Basemap` as I already stated in my answer. :-)

Comment: @martijn-pieters thank you, I saw the update to your answer now. Works wonderfully.